# Azure Devops Pipeline to deploy one repository to multiple Azure services

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

I am trying to create a pipeline to deploy one solution on multiple Azure services.

Let's say I have a solution 'TemberSolution' with following projects

1. FunctionsProject -> should be deployed on 'AppFunctions'
2. SupportProject -> should be deployed on AKS containers

how can i achieve this in devops pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 builds and 2 releases. I dont see any problem with this approach.

If you want a single build and single release (makes no sense), you can still do that, you can use environments to distinguish between where\how you release which app

Comment: well thanks for answering my question.

i have little different situation here, i want to deploy one code repository hosted on Git to multiple services.
The repo contains one solution when i export the artifacts they are created as one "drop.zip".
whereas my repository code has a solution and the solution has following projects.
1. FunctionsProject
2. SupportProject

now the artifact should be deployed on following services in following order.
1. FunctionsProject should be deployed on 'AppService' managed service.
2. SupportProject should be deployed on 'AKS' Containers service.

Comment: but where is the problem? for aks you build a container, not a drop.zip. even if you did have a single drop.zip its a matter of creating 2 different build artifacts, which isnt exactly rocket science

Comment: You can deploy the same artifact to multiple azure services with all your services in a drop.zip ready for release. Then just wire together release tasks sequentially to deploy the code to multiple services. (NB you can create 2 deployment phases 1 to deploy the function the other your supporting service). The previous answer is correct, the usual pattern for AKS deployments would not to use your drop.zip, but for this container to be pushed to a container registry (like Azure Container Registry) where in your release you can deploy this service directly out of the ACR registry into AKS.