# Azure Devops 2 webservices in one solution (and one repository)

Tags: azure-devops

My question is simular to:[Azure Devops Pipeline to deploy one repository to multiple Azure services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394849/azure-devops-pipeline-to-deploy-one-repository-to-multiple-azure-services)
In my solution, I have a bunch of projects, but the focus: 1 REST API, 1 SOAP service(yes, gotta love it)
I have created 2 web apps in azure. Each for one of them.

In my Devops I have the straightforward:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
```

So I guess I need to BUILD the 2 projects (csproj) and also publish the artifacts. And then with the release I need to point the right artifacts. But... I do not know how.

The structure of the solution is;

- Solution

  - API.csproj
  - SOAP.csproj
  - other projects

thnx for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two VS build tasks and two Publish Build Artifacts tasks to build and publish the two projects separately. Then you will get two artifacts and can download them separately with `Download Pipeline Artifacts` task in your release.

[image]

Sample  yaml:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/API.csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\API\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/SOAP.csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\SOAP\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\API\WebApp.zip'
    artifact: 'API'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\SOAP\WebApp.zip'
    artifact: 'SOAP'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Comment: great thnx!! this is putting me in the right direction.

Comment: Do receive another error on the SOAP: baseOutputPath/outputPath property is not set for project SOAP.csproj Let me google this :) Thnx so far man!

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: i tried something simular on an executable. I want to execute the executable on the release, not in this pipeline. But whatever i am trying; it tells me on the publish artifact that it is going wrong. Can you help with the arguments on the new VSBuild task?